# GIT: Слияние с заменой

Tags: git, git-merge, sh

Подскажите команду слияния, при которой все файлы с 1 ветки переместились бы во 2 с приоритетом 1 ветки.

К примеру, есть ветки master, и build.
В ветке build находятся скомпилированные файлы master.
Пишу скрипт автокомпиляции, что-то на подобии этого:

```
git checkout build
git merge -s ours master
./compile
```

Как я понял, это можно реализовать с помощью ours/theirs, но так и не понял, как именно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такое решение должно подойти:

```
git checkout --theirs ветка -- .
```

Где `ветка` - ветка-источник, находиться нужно в ветке-цели